# How to add a phrase in template to translate in prestashop 1.7.6?

Tags: internationalization, prestashop, translation

I added code:

`{l s='Place the order' d='Shop.Theme.Checkout'}`

in template file: `...\prestashop\themes\classic\templates\checkout\_partials\steps\payment.tpl` , but it does not appear in translation panel in my 1.7.6 Prestashop admin.

So how do I add a phrase to be able to translate it?

In previous versions of prestashop it was enough to modify the template to make phrase appear in translation panel but in new version it doesn't work ...

**EDIT:**

I read that new translations are not recognized if added to `classic` theme, so I made child theme and I can see new string in translator. But there is new issue, the translation is not saved, although message 'Translation updated' appears

Here are my steps:

1. create empty child theme (named: stg) of classic theme
2. copy a template file from classic theme to my theme preserving path ( templates\checkout_partials\steps\payment.tpl)
3. add a new string to a copied template with domain: Shop.Stgtheme
4. there is only one exported language file of my theme named: pl-PL.pl-PL.xlf (no ShopStgtheme.pl-PL.xlf in zip) and no new string in exported file, maybe that is the issue?
5. rename exported file (pl-PL.pl-PL.xlf) to: ShopStgtheme.pl-PL.xlf into themes/stg/translations/pl-PL otherwise translator adds wrong domains in domain tree
6. new string is recognized and appears in theme translator within domain: Stgtheme, but is not saved after clicking Save button

Comment: no new files or new lines in the table translations ? did you tried to clear your cache ? (translations are saved in the var/cache/[dev|prod]/translations folder)

Comment: Can you try to clear the cache, and reload FO/BO to recreate cache file. Then open cache file to see if the translation is in it, and in this case, what is its domain. Else, it's a Prestashop problem (:0, I will try to create the same bug you got

Comment: @FanieVoid I cleared the cache and translation is not in cache file, so it seems to be PS problem, I reported the issue here if you want to follow it: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/15791

Answer (score 1):

See [this documentation](https://build.prestashop.com/howtos/translation/how-to-translate-your-theme), I think you are in the 2nd case.

Seems you have to extract your theme translations first and them re-insert them into your prestashop. Now you can translate your new blocks

Comment: Thanks for info. I followed the documentation but still have issue - see my edit

Answer (score 1):

Prestashop search for new string in themes, only if the theme in use is not Classic. So to add some translable text you have to assign it to a custom module, in your tpl file use

```
{l s='Place the order' mod='already_existing_and_active_module_name'}
```

then you will find your string into this module's translation